# pivot then group on value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `logs` table with the following definition:

```
   Column         |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id               | integer               |           | not null |
 work_location_id | uuid                  |           | not null |
 hard_disk_id     | integer               |           | not null |
```

and a `works` table with the following definition:

```
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | integer               |           | not null |
 location_id | uuid                  |           | not null |
 f_index     | integer               |           | not null |
 f_name      | character varying(40) |           | not null |
 f_value     | character varying(40) |           | not null |
```

The `logs` table has data such as:

```
 id |          work_location_id            | hard_disk_id 
----+--------------------------------------+--------------
  1 | 40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608 | 1
  2 | 3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36 | 2
  3 | c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc | 3
  4 | 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 | 4
  5 | 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 | 5
```

And the `works` table has data such as:

```
 id |             location_id              | f_index |   f_name    |  f_value
----+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------+------------
  1 | 40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608 |       1 | plot_crop   | pears
  2 | 3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36 |       1 | plot_crop   | pears
  3 | c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc |       1 | plot_crop   | pears
  4 | 1cdc7c05-0acd-46cb-b48a-4d3e240a4548 |       1 | plot_crop   | pears
  5 | dae1eee7-508f-4a76-8906-8ff7b8bfab26 |       1 | plot_crop   | pears
  6 | 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 |       1 | plot_id     | 137
  7 | 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 |       2 | farmer_name | John Smith
```

**Desired Output**

I want to be able to query the two tables and get the following output

```
              location_id              | plot_id | farmer_name
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------
  40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608 | None    | None
  3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36 | None    | None
  c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc | None    | None
  6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 | 137     | John Smith
```

Notice how for `location_id = 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836`, both values are now showing in one row. I tried to use `group by location_id` but that didn't work, I was still getting duplicates.

I have also created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kD5CdkGguHyd91GGvvZGY/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like conditional aggregation:

```
select location_id,
       max(f_value) filter (where f_name = 'plot_id') as plot_id,
       max(f_value) filter (where f_name = 'farmer_name') as farmer_name
from t
group by location_id;
```

In other databases, you would just use:

```
max(case when f_name = 'plot_id' then f_value end) as plot_id
```

Comment: I'd like this to work in other database engines too, such as MS SQL, am I right that `filter` wouldn't work there?

Comment: @J86 . . . I edited the answer, but that is not the question you asked here.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should have made that clear. Let me give your updated answer a go.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to have None as text

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
-- create table
create table logs (
  id integer not null,
  work_location_id uuid not null,
  hard_disk_id integer not null
);

create table works (
    id integer not null,
    location_id uuid not null,
    f_index integer not null,
    f_name varchar(40) not null,
    f_value varchar(40) not null
);

-- insert data into table
insert into logs (id, work_location_id, hard_disk_id) values
    (1, '40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608', 1),
    (2, '3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36', 2),
    (3, 'c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc', 3),
    (4, '6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836', 4),
    (5, '6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836', 5);

insert into works (id, location_id, f_index, f_name, f_value) values
    (1, '40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608', 1, 'plot_crop', 'pears'),
    (2, '3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36', 1, 'plot_crop', 'pears'),
    (3, 'c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc', 1, 'plot_crop', 'pears'),
    (4, '1cdc7c05-0acd-46cb-b48a-4d3e240a4548', 1, 'plot_crop', 'pears'),
    (5, 'dae1eee7-508f-4a76-8906-8ff7b8bfab26', 1, 'plot_crop', 'pears'),
    (6, '6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836', 1, 'plot_id', '137'),
    (7, '6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836', 2, 'farmer_name', 'John Smith');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select w.location_id,
       COALESCE(MAX(case
           when w.f_name = 'plot_id' then w.f_value
           else NULL
       end),'None')  as "plot_id",
       COALESCE(MAX(case
           when w.f_name = 'farmer_name' then w.f_value
           else NULL
       end),'None') as "farmer_name"
from logs l
inner join works w on w.location_id = l.work_location_id
GROUP BY location_id;
```

| location_id | plot_id | farmer_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3f333df6-90a4-4fda-8dd3-9485d27cee36 | None | None |
| 40e6215d-b5c6-4896-987c-f30f3678f608 | None | None |
| 6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836 | 137 | John Smith |
| c17bed94-3a9c-4c21-be49-dc77f96d49dc | None | None |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kD5CdkGguHyd91GGvvZGY/2)